# Remove background, reflection and shadows with Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have images where I would like to make the background transparent, remove the shadow and remove the product reflection.

So what I want to do is

- Remove reflection
- Remove shadow
- Remove background

---

### Test image

[image]

Comment: Can you show before and after shots? I'm not overly knowledgeable about imagemagick, but it seems like you might be asking too much of the program.

Comment: Updated with a before and after image only

Comment: If I click on the second image, I see no background, whereas the first image has a white background... So It seems good to me, no ?

Comment: Updated to be more clear in what I want to achieve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, you can threshold the image and get the bounds of the black area. Then crop the original to those bounds.

```
convert image.png -threshold 50% +write image_thresh50.png -format "%@" info:
229x367+39+0
```

[image]

```
convert image.png -crop 229x367+39+0 +repage image_cropped.png
```

[image]

If using Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Will try this out!.. thx!.. could you explain the steps taken here? Never really worked with ImageMagick before so not sure what happens here :)

Comment: I take it that "229x367+39+0" are width, height etc.. but what I want to do this for a batch of different images?

Comment: The first code is getting the dimensions which are used in the second command. If on V6 you can save those dimension into a variable and use them in the second command. In V7 you may be able to do it all in one command.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Bonzo's comment, in Unix ImageMagick 6, I could do:

```
cropvals=$(convert image.png -threshold 50% +write hAfUS_thresh50.png -format "%@" info:)
convert image.png -crop $cropvals +repage image_cropped.png
```

And in Unix, Imagemagick 7, I could do:

```
magick image.png \( +clone -threshold 50% -set option:cropvals "%@" +delete \) -crop "%[cropvals]" +repage image_cropped2.png
```

The reason I did not post these was because I did not know what OS/Platform the OP was using. It always helps when asking questions about Imagemagick to post its version and the platform it is run on.

Sorry I do not know how to do this in Windows syntax

Comment: Sorry... should have said IM 7 on Unix :).. tried it out and the result is ok on several images. but for some there are some strange cropping.. will see if I can figure it out tomorrow.. big thx for your guidance!